# Oracle 12c - Trying to create a simple function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a simple function in oracle which is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upd_film() 
    RETURN trigger
IS
BEGIN
    IF (old.title != new.title) or (old.description != new.description)
    THEN
        UPDATE film_text
            SET title=new.title,
                description=new.description,
                film_id=new.film_id
        WHERE film_id=old.film_id;
    END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

And getting following compilation errors :

```
UPD_FILM
FUNCTION          1      1     19
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
```

Your help would be much appreciated !!
Many thanks !
Tonya

EDIT:

I am actually porting a mysql database called SAKILA over to oracle and yes I will call this function from a trigger as under :

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_film AFTER UPDATE ON film FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION upd_film();
```

I believe in oracle you can just achieve it by using just a trigger but I don't know PL/SQL, please help me write a trigger which does it - Thanks you.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with this function? it seems that you are trying to build a (weird) update trigger, not a function.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  You say that you're trying to create a function.  But the code makes it appear that you're trying to create a trigger.  If you are trying to create a function, you can't refer to `:old` and `:new` pseudorecords.  And you can't return a `trigger` (unless you've somehow defined your own type that you've inexplicably named `trigger`).

Comment: Remove the parenthesis in the function declaration. Also, I don't think you can return a trigger, which itself is another totally different object. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `RETURN trigger` is invalid. After the keyword `return` you must specify a datatype: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS2178

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upd_film
AFTER UPDATE
   ON film
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (:old.title != :new.title) or (:old.description != :new.description)
    THEN
        UPDATE film_text
            SET title=:new.title,
                description=:new.description,
                film_id=:new.film_id
        WHERE film_id=:old.film_id;
    END IF;
END;
/
```